# Right way to interact between services

Tags: angular

So now in my Service I have function with post method and in "component A" I send data to this post request. In "component B" I just need to get the response data, for that I store the response in BehaviourSubject and I'm subscribing to it (cause I have nothing to send from this component to service function).

1) It's working. But is this a best practies and proper usage of BehaviourSubject ? [looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khys4.png)

Ok, I want to restructure it by adding class. Now I have the same service and 2 components, also I'm creating a class and service with get method and in my components I should call it. But again it's OK when I'm sending smth to it, but in "component B" I need just to get the data and it's saying me that I should send him smth.

2) How do it in the right way? [structure I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Z1E.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're getting at, in a similar situation I've exposed a method that does a `getValue()` on the `BehaviourSubject` so that it's possible to directly inquire about the current state of the `BehaviourSubject`'s value without there having to be an event that changes that value.

For example, here's what I did to coordinate a time value between components:

```
public get time(): number { return this._time.getValue(); }
public set time(newTime: number) {
  if (this._time.getValue() !== newTime)
    this._time.next(newTime);
}
public getTimeUpdates(callback: (time: number) => void): Subscription {
  return this.timeObserver.subscribe(callback);
}
```